# Why is my Angular SPA not identifying the google classroom share button element (<g:sharetoclassroom>)?

Tags: html, angular, google-classroom

tl;dr
I am receiving the following error when trying to add the google classroom share button to my web app (angular 5, spa):

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
':g:sharetoclassroom' is not a known element:
1. If ':g:sharetoclassroom' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    </div>
    <div class="qr-code">
        [ERROR ->]<g:sharetoclassroom url="..." size="32"></g:sharetoclassroom>
    </div>
  </div>
"): ng:///AppModule/ShareLinkComponent.html@18:8
```

I want to add the [google classroom share button](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton#a_simple_button) to my web app, but I can't figure out why the share button element is not being identified.
I've added the script (`<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>`) into the `<head>` in `index.html`. I've added the share button element to one of the components:

```
<!-- share-link.component.html -->

<mat-dialog-content>
  <div i18n class="share-link-text">
      Share the assessment link with your students.
  </div>
  <div class="share-container">
    <div class="share-to-classroom">
        <g:sharetoclassroom url="http://url-to-share" size="32"></g:sharetoclassroom>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
```

But when I run the code locally I am getting the error `':g:sharetoclassroom' is not a known element`. I really don't understand what is happening/missing. 
**Oddly when I add the element into the `index.html` (not in any other component) the share button actually appears & works as expected.**
Anyone aware of any issues with loading 3rd party scripts/using gapi/using 3rd party elements that don't (seemingly) need to be added into the AppModule?

I've tried putting the script directly in the component, added the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA to the @NgModule.schemas (which suppressed the error, but the button simply didn't appear, had 0x0 dimensions...). I'm out of creative ideas, but will add that I'm not much of an angular expert...

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your module as the error suggests. The problem is angular cant recognise component `g:sharetoclassroom`, because its a webcomponent, declared outside of angular's scope. You need to tell angular this via `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`. Which basically allow you to add external webcomponents in that module.

```
@NgModule({
…
schemas: [
   NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
]
})
```

Edit:
I can't see webcomponent's script being loaded in your code. Pls make sure to do that after webcomponent tag (**without** `async` and `defer`).

Comment: `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` suppressed the error, and the element technically appears but with 0x0 dimensions and of course doesn't work.
What do you mean by loading the script after the webcomponent tag? I've removed the `async` and `defer` and the script is in the `<head>` of `index.html`.

Comment: Maya Iz, Are you resolve above issue? How do you do that?